# Cell space in table

Tags: tables

is there any chance I can set up the cell length in a table? My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[scale=.75,textheight=27cm, textwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}

\begin{document}

% Table 1
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\normalsize{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{\textbf{List of ountry \label{sumstat}}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c} }\hline\hline
\multirow{2}[3]{*}{\textbf{Country}}& \multirow{2}[3]{*}{\textbf{GDP}} & \textbf{Political}& \textbf{Globalization} & \textbf{Growth Rate} \\
& & \textbf{Competition} & \textbf{Degree}& \textbf{1970--2010}  \\
\hline
Argentina& 125 & 9 & 34.5 & 9\% \\
Argentina& 125 & 9 & 34.5 & 9\%
\\\hline \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}\pagebreak



\end{document}
```

If you try to compile it, we can see that the cells are not equally spaced unfortunately. Thanks in advance

Comment: With column types `p{<width>}` or `m{<width>}` or with `X` from `tabularx` package. And please, reduce your code to minimal working example.

Comment: You wrote, "the cells are not equally spaced". Please be more specific about your objectives. E.g., should all five columns be equally wide, or should only columns 2 thru 5 be equally wide. For that matter, how wide should the overall table be?

Comment: @Mico you are right. I was vague. I need all the columns in the table to have the same width. The table should be in total 10 cm width, i.e. 2/3 of the total width of the page.

Comment: `\normalsize` does not take an argument so  the braces in `\normalsize{` just add an unwanted group (and a space token)

Comment: `c` columns are the width of their content, you could use `p` or better here use siunitx S column formatted to a specific width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tabularx` package and its `tabularx` environment to set up a table which (a) is 10cm wide overall and (b) has 5 equal-width columns. Use either left-aligned (aka ragged-right) or centered versions of the package's `X` column type. (Since each column is less than 2cm wide, full justification of the column contents is bound to look quite bad.)

I would also like recommend that you **use much less boldface**; ideally, use none at all in a table. That way, you'll avoid creating the impression that you like to **shout** at your readers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% preamble deliberately simplified 
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hspace{0pt}\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[textheight=27cm,textwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

% Table 1
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\caption{List of [c]ountr[ies]}  \label{sumstat}
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{@{} L *{4}{C} @{}}  % 5 columns total, all equally wide
\toprule
Country& GDP & Political Competition& Globalization Degree & Growth Rate 1970--2010 \\
\midrule
Argentina& 125 & 9 & 34.5 & 9\% \\
Argentina& 125 & 9 & 34.5 & 9\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just trying to understand why is it written like this  `[c]ountr[ies]`

Comment: @jsbibra - The OP had written `List of ountry` That didn't seem right. By writing `[c]ountr[ies]`, I meant to indicate that I was supplying a `c` and was replacing `y` with `ies`. In retrospect, probably much too subtle...

Comment: Thought it was a macro call or something similar